# How to implement a transaction-safe, random sequence in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, innodb, sequence

So my app needs to let users generate *random* alphanumeric codes like A6BU31, 38QV3B, R6RK7T. Currently they consist of 6 chars, whereas I and O are not used (so we got 34^6 possibilities). These codes are then printed out and used for something else.

I must now ensure that many users can "reserve" up to 100 codes per request, so user A might want to get 50 codes, user B wants to generate 10 and so on. These codes must be unique across all users, so user A and user B may not both receive the code ABC123.

My current approach (using PHP and MySQL) is to have two InnoDB tables for this:

- One (the "repository") contains a large list of pre-generated codes (since the possibility of collisions will increase over time and I do not want to go the try-insert-if-fails-try-another-code approach). The repository contains just the codes and an auto-incremented ID (so I can sort them, see below).
- The other table holds the reserved keys (i.e. code + owning user).

Whenever a user wants to reserve N keys, I planned to do the following

```sql
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO revered_codes (code,user_id)
  SELECT code FROM repository WHERE 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT N;
DELETE FROM repository WHERE 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT N;
COMMIT;
```

This *should* work, but I'm not sure. It seems like I'm building a WTF solution.

After insertion I must select the just reserved codes to display them to the user. And that's the tricky part, since I don't really know how to identify the just reserved codes after my transaction is done. I could of course add just another column to my `reserved_codes` table, holding some kind of random token, but this seems even more WTFy.

My favorite solution would be to have a random number sequence, so that I can just perform `INSERT` operations in the `reserved_codes` table.

So, how to do this unique, random and transactional-safe sequence in MySQL? One idea was to have a regular auto-increment on the `reserved_codes` table and derive the random code value from that numeric column, but I was wondering whether there was a better way.

**UPDATE:** I forgot to mention that it would be advantagous to have a rather small table of reserved codes, as I later have to find single codes again for updating them (`reserved_codes` has a couple of more attributes to it). So letting the reserved table grow slowly is good (instead of having a huge index over ~1mio pre-generated codes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you already have a repository table, I would just add a user column and then run this query:

```
UPDATE repository SET user_id = ? WHERE user_id IS NULL LIMIT N;
```

Afterwards, you can select the records again. This had two distinct disadvantages:

- you need an index on `user_id`
- you can't use the codes in your table for anything else but binding it to users.

Comment: The index on user_id would be really bad IMHO (but don't know if I can really avoid it, though), because I got only a handful users, so the index would not be that selective. What exactly do you mean with your second point of not having any more columns in my table? Wouldn't it be okay to have the table be `(code VARCHAR, user INT, created DATE, used DATE, color VARCHAR)`?

Comment: But nonetheless, I really like the simplicity. I would just have to make sure my one table has always a bunch of unused codes available, and that can be taken care of by a simple cronjob. No need to sync two tables and move rows from one to the other.

Comment: I wasn't sure how many records you have, so an index may or may not be bad :) my second point is just theoretical in the sense that you can't assign codes to non-users (you may never have this scenario). This still leaves you with perhaps having to clean up used records, but that should not be very hard.